# Команды ветвления ассемблера мк51: как перейти на на адрес не объявляя метку?

Tags: ассемблер, микроконтроллеры

Существует команда перехода:

```
JMP label
```

Я бы хотел не объявлять метку, а прямо указать смещение относительно текущего значения счетчика команд.
Вопрос как это сделать?

Comment: Скорее всего никак. Вряд-ли какой-то транслятор (если только самописный) поддерживает такие фокусы. Но на ассемблере всегда можно прямо вставить шестнадцатеричный код команды в последовательность команд.

Comment: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_jmp.htm И как вы себе предствляете запись такой команды? Пробовали просто `jmp` без параметров? А вот пробовали http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_ajmp.htm?